# Node js express validator throwing error

Tags: node.js, express, npm, express-validator

I have installed express validator, but throwing error as follows:

express-validator@5.2.0

> shopping-cart@0.0.0 start /var/www/nodejs/shopping-cart
>   node ./bin/www

```
/var/www/nodejs/shopping-cart/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:4
const { checkSchema, validationResult } = require('../check');
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodejs/shopping-cart/node_modules/express-validator/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)

npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! shopping-cart@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the shopping-cart@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the shopping-cart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs shopping-cart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls shopping-cart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/nodejs/shopping-cart/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using?

Comment: Your version of node is too old to be using object destructuring. Update.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is from ES6, which node version 4 does not support. Please update node.js version, which is recommended, because node 4 maintenance period ended.

Answer (score 0):

The Object Destructuring syntax is from ES6/ECMAScript 2015.

The latest version of Node.js 6.x supports 93% of ES6 features.